# Recommendations for a GIS hosting platform to publish to customers

Tags: web-server, gis

I'm doing some research for my company - looking for any recommendations for a GIS platform where we can publish in-house geospatial data to our stakeholders and customers, and my knowledge of such platforms is very limited.

We're looking for a few options in order to produce a business case with the various options/costs. We are based in the UK (if that makes any difference).

Requirements:
 - we must be able to upload custom layers (ie- we know some layers/data we want to share, but there will also be data we can't anticipate)
 - must have a customer/stakeholder-side login that define what layers a customer/stakeholder can see (some customer data is confidential and some data is for internal use only)
 - must be able to host project information (pdfs, images, videos), linked to geospatial attributes, to communicate with customers

Nice to have:
 - we would like to be able to filter some layers based on other layers (ie- show all projects in London/customer boundaries/etc)
 - analytic functions and reports from pre-defined layers

My first thought was ESRI and ArcGIS and that can do everything on the list and more - but are there any other credible options?

We are in the preliminary stages of research right now, and just finding out what is possible and available.